# Is dBase file according to specifications

Tags: dbase

Please consider a DBF file with a field N(7,3). Is it allowed to store 9999.99 in such a field? In my mind 999.999 is the largest number allowed and -99.999 is the smallest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct on your 999.999.  The full amount allows for 3 whole digits (or - plus 2 digits) decimal for 4th position and 3 more actual decimal.